# Load function in jQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, footer

I am trying to load a header and footer file into jQuery, so I wrote the following code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#header").load("testheader.html");
            $("#footer").load("testfooter.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <p> Hello World! </p>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, nothing loads from header and footer. I searched around StackOverflow and they talked about how if you import the wrong library you wouldn't get the load function properly. I tried to import different sources of jquery but nothing works. Please helpp!!  Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting **any** errors in the developer tools console

Comment: as long as those files exist (`testheader.html` and `testfooter.html`) in the **same folder as the main file**, this works as is, no need to change your already correctly written jqueery

Comment: Hi I tried opening the html in firefox, turns out that it works in firefox but not in chrome. Why did it happen?

Comment: chrome has developer tools (F12), which has a console, which should show errors

Comment: thanks for the tip! @JaromandaX The error msg is "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.".... I uploaded my files onto github and it worked!